# How do you change Window Control Position in the Unity Panel?

Tags: unity, 11.04, window-buttons

Currently, my window decorations are in the top left as per the default Ubuntu, but I have reordered them to "Minimize, Maximize, Close"
However on Unity Desktop, when I maximize my window, and the Unity Panel takes over window decorations, It switches back to the default "Close, Minimize, Maximize"
I tried poking around gconf and couldn't find anything, anybody have a tweak?

Comment: Bug Reported: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/708653

Answer (score 3):

Can you file a bug for this over at https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity

Comment: Also, when you file the bug. Please report back here with a link, so those who are interested can track it.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/708653

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that. Ayatana indicators have been designed with consistency in mind and one of the elements of a consistent UI is permanent position of indicators. I don't think you can reorder the elements of the unity panel at all. You can remove some if you like but reordering is just not possible (AFAIK).

Comment: I think the question was referring to window control buttons (close, minimmise, maximise) and not indicators.

Comment: Well, everything in the unity-panel follows the same rules. :P